# How can I create an array of observable/http requests based on keys in an array that are returned from another observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

So I'm trying to wrap my head around Observables, and for the most part they make sense - but all the docs assume you're actually working with a stream of data - and Angular makes every http call default to an observable, even though these are not streams, but isolate values returned, which is causing some confusion for me.

So, I'm making an http call, which returns an array of objects. I then need to map over that array, and spawn a new http call based on a key within each object. Then I need to collect all the responses from those calls, and map over the initial array to set a property based on the responses from that second array of calls.

Excuse the Sudo Code

```
this._http.get<>(url).subscribe(value => myData = value);
```

which returns an array like

```
[
{ clientId: 1, ..additional properties},
{ clientId: 2, ..additional properties},
]
```

Then I need to map over this and spawn new http calls like so

```
response.map(item => {
 this._http.get(`someurl/${item.clientId})
}
```

Then I need to combine all of those calls into a single block of data, so that I can do something like

```
myData.map(item => {
item.fullClient = ArrayOfClientReturns.find(client => client.id === item.clientId);
}
```

My problem is I totally understand how to do this with promises, but with observables, I am really not sure. I understand how to use pipe(map()) to combine observables, but I don't understand how to map over an array of data and spawn a collection of observables BASED ON the response of the initial observable, then wait for them all to resolve, then re-map over the initial data set like this.

I'm sure I'm just missing the correct method in the rxjs docs, but every example shows combining observables that already exist before you try to combine them.

If someone could point me in the correct direction I'd be thankful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're absolutely on the right path, you should be able to make use of something like `forkJoin`, which will join an array of `Observables`

```
 this._http.get<any[]>(url).pipe(
        mergeMap(arr => forkJoin(arr.map((item) => this._http.get(`someurl/${item.clientId}`).pipe(map((name) => {
           item.name = name;
           return item;
        })
 ))))
```

Here, we use the array `map` function to convert the array of objects into an array of `Observable`s. We then use `forkJoin` to combine the array of observables into one, and we use `mergeMap` to join it to the original request.

(Please note this is using the new rxjs syntax, with `pipe`, but it can be done with the older syntax as well)

Comment: This got me a bit further but ends up returing nothing for me.


    return programDocuments$.pipe(mergeMap(documents => 
    forkJoin(documents.map(item => this._http.get(`employee/2079/full-name`)))));

ends up returning [], and I'm not sure why

Comment: @trattles It should return an Observable that you'll need to subscribe to

Comment: So another issue, that second endpoint that takes the ID returns only a string - so I need some way to maintain a mapping of ids to the responses...:/

Comment: It does return an observable. the subscribed observable emits []

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Can you try to console log the length of `documents` before doing the `map`? Sounds like it may be empty

Comment: documents length is 2. If I return just the documents observable (and don't do the mapping stuff, so I don't have the client object) it correctly contains 2 documents with all the other properties.

Comment: So here's my actual code, to give you a better example

```
let programDocuments$ = this._http.get<ProgramDocument[]>(url);
    return programDocuments$.pipe(
      mergeMap(documentArray => forkJoin(documentArray.map(item => this._http.get(`employee/2079/full-name`, { responseType: 'text' }))))
    );

```

That returns just the names in in the subscription, ie: ["bob", "bob"]

But note: even if it also returned the documents, the problem would be that I don't have the ID mappings to those names because that endpoint returns only a string.

Honestly I might just use promises.

Comment: Hang on, is it emitting an empty array, or an array of names?

Comment: An array of names.  Only names, no documents. And the names have no mapping to the original Id used to request them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182953/discussion-between-user184994-and-trattles).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks so much. I think I understand observables considerably better now.